# how to set cleditor font for <p> or any other tag?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, cleditor

I want to post a text from a `textarea` to another html page.

But when I paste the text in the `textarea` the font and size does not follow my styles!
I've set the `textarea` and `<p>` font size and font-family but it did not help.

```
<textarea class="cleditor" id="textarea2"name="about" rows="3"></textarea>

    .cleditorMain {border:1px solid #ddd; padding:0 1px 1px; background-color:white}
    .cleditorMain iframe {border:none; margin:0; padding:0}
    .cleditorMain textarea {border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow-y:scroll; dir:rtl; font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-weight:normal;resize:none;outline:none /* webkit grip focus */}
    .cleditorToolbar {background: url('../img/toolbar.gif') repeat}
    .cleditorGroup {float:left; height:26px}
    .cleditorButton {float:left; width:24px; height:24px; margin:1px 0 1px 0;background: url('../img/buttons.gif')}
    .cleditorDisabled {opacity:0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=30)}
    .cleditorDivider {float:left; width:1px; height:23px; margin:1px 0 1px 0; background:#CCC}
    .cleditorPopup {border:solid 1px #999; background-color:white; position:absolute; font:10pt Arial,Verdana; cursor:default; z-index:10000}
    .cleditorList div {padding:2px 4px 2px 4px}
    .cleditorList p,
    .cleditorList h1,
    .cleditorList h2,
    .cleditorList h3,
    .cleditorList h4,
    .cleditorList h5,
    .cleditorList h6,
    .cleditorList font {padding:0; margin:0; background-color:Transparent}
    .cleditorColor {width:150px; padding:1px 0 0 1px}
    .cleditorColor div {float:left; width:14px; height:14px; margin:0 1px 1px 0}
    .cleditorPrompt {background-color:#F6F7F9; padding:4px; font-size:8.5pt}
    .cleditorPrompt input,
    .cleditorPrompt textarea {font:8.5pt Arial,Verdana;}
    .cleditorMsg {background-color:#FDFCEE; width:150px; padding:4px; font-size:8.5pt}
```

html code

```
    <p class="about-p">
         {!! $about['about'] !!}
    </p>
```

css

```
.about-p{
     font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
     font-weight:normal;
     text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: please add your html,css code,otherwise we can just predict

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly as it will vastly improve your chances of getting good answers in return and not have your question downvoted or closed.

Comment: if you want to explicitly set particular `font` for all `tags` then you can do something like `* { font-family: cursive !important;}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
    .cleditorList p{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;!important; font-weight:normal;}
```

styles should be added in this line.

Answer (score 0):

To select only one element, or class name, or ID... Only select that element:

```
textarea {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.font-normal {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
```

You can comma separate selectors to assign that one font to multiple elements as well:

```
div, p, textarea, .font-sans-serif {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cleditor,please check that you've added scripts and css files.
 [there is a simple demo](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/simpledemo)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can force the CSS to follow your fonts specification by simply adding the !important label after the textarea property. 
Like this

```
textarea {font-family: Helvetica !important;}
```

Manually rewriting them all in this format, placing the label after the property value should force the CSS to automatically give your CSS rule more priority.